# How can I append a button with data-toggle attribute?

Tags: jquery, append

I have a button that opens a sidebar, when I click on it. When I append the same button to my box and the click on it, it is not opening the sidebar:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="control-sidebar">Toggle Right Sidebar</button>
```

```js
$(document).off("click", ".click").on("click", ".click", function (event) {
  $(".box").append(stuff);
});

var stuff = $('<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="control-sidebar">This button is not opening the sidebar. Why?</button>');




$.AdminLTE = {};
$.AdminLTE.options = {
    enableControlSidebar: true,
    controlSidebarOptions: {
        toggleBtnSelector: "[data-toggle='control-sidebar']",
        selector: ".control-sidebar",
        slide: false
    },
};

$(function () {
    "use strict";

    $("body").removeClass("hold-transition");

    if (typeof AdminLTEOptions !== "undefined") {
        $.extend(true,
            $.AdminLTE.options,
            AdminLTEOptions);
    }

    var o = $.AdminLTE.options;

    _init();

    $.AdminLTE.tree('.sidebar');

    if (o.enableControlSidebar) {
        $.AdminLTE.controlSidebar.activate();
    }

    if (o.sidebarPushMenu) {
        $.AdminLTE.pushMenu.activate(o.sidebarToggleSelector);
    }


});


function _init() {
    'use strict';
 
    $.AdminLTE.layout = {
        activate: function () {
            var _this = this;
            _this.fix();
            _this.fixSidebar();
            $(window, ".wrapper").resize(function () {
                _this.fix();
                _this.fixSidebar();
            });
        },
        fix: function () {

            var neg = $('.main-header').outerHeight() + $('.main-footer').outerHeight();
            var window_height = $(window).height();
            var sidebar_height = $(".sidebar").height();
            if ($("body").hasClass("fixed")) {
                $(".content-wrapper, .right-side").css('min-height', window_height - $('.main-footer').outerHeight());
            } else {
                var postSetWidth;
                if (window_height >= sidebar_height) {
                    $(".content-wrapper, .right-side").css('min-height', window_height - neg);
                    postSetWidth = window_height - neg;
                } else {
                    $(".content-wrapper, .right-side").css('min-height', sidebar_height);
                    postSetWidth = sidebar_height;
                }

                var controlSidebar = $($.AdminLTE.options.controlSidebarOptions.selector);
                if (typeof controlSidebar !== "undefined") {
                    if (controlSidebar.height() > postSetWidth)
                        $(".content-wrapper, .right-side").css('min-height', controlSidebar.height());
                }

            }
        },
        fixSidebar: function () {
            if (!$("body").hasClass("fixed")) {
                if (typeof $.fn.slimScroll != 'undefined') {
                    $(".sidebar").slimScroll({
                        destroy: true
                    }).height("auto");
                }
                return;
            } else if (typeof $.fn.slimScroll == 'undefined' && window.console) {
                window.console.error("Error: the fixed layout requires the slimscroll plugin!");
            }
            if ($.AdminLTE.options.sidebarSlimScroll) {
                if (typeof $.fn.slimScroll != 'undefined') {
           
                    $(".sidebar").slimScroll({
                        destroy: true
                    }).height("auto");
             
                    $(".sidebar").slimscroll({
                        height: ($(window).height() - $(".main-header").height()) + "px",
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
                        size: "3px"
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };


    $.AdminLTE.tree = function (menu) {
        var _this = this;
        var animationSpeed = $.AdminLTE.options.animationSpeed;
        $(document).off('click', menu + ' li a')
            .on('click', menu + ' li a', function (e) {
            
                var $this = $(this);
                var checkElement = $this.next();

                if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (checkElement.is(':visible')) && (!$('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse'))) {
              
                    checkElement.slideUp(animationSpeed, function () {
                        checkElement.removeClass('menu-open');
                 
                    });
                    checkElement.parent("li").removeClass("active");
                }
          
                else if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
               
                    var parent = $this.parents('ul').first();
            
                    var ul = parent.find('ul:visible').slideUp(animationSpeed);
                
                    ul.removeClass('menu-open');
            
                    var parent_li = $this.parent("li");

                    checkElement.slideDown(animationSpeed, function () {
                   
                        checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
                        parent.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
                        parent_li.addClass('active');
                       
                        _this.layout.fix();
                    });
                }
       
                if (checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
    };


    $.AdminLTE.controlSidebar = {

        activate: function () {
      
            var _this = this;
            var o = $.AdminLTE.options.controlSidebarOptions;
            var sidebar = $(o.selector);

            var btn = $(o.toggleBtnSelector);

            btn.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                _this.open(sidebar, o.slide);
  
            });

            $(".close_sidebar").on('click', function (e) {
                _this.close(sidebar, o.slide);
            });

            var bg = $(".control-sidebar-bg");
            _this._fix(bg);

            if ($('body').hasClass('fixed')) {
                _this._fixForFixed(sidebar);
            } else {
            
                if ($('.content-wrapper, .right-side').height() < sidebar.height()) {
                    _this._fixForContent(sidebar);
                }
            }
        },
        open: function (sidebar, slide) {
 
            if (slide) {
                sidebar.addClass('control-sidebar-open');
            } else {
         
                $('body').addClass('control-sidebar-open');
            }
        },

        close: function (sidebar, slide) {
            if (slide) {
                sidebar.removeClass('control-sidebar-open');
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass('control-sidebar-open');
            }
        },
        _fix: function (sidebar) {
            var _this = this;
            if ($("body").hasClass('layout-boxed')) {
                sidebar.css('position', 'absolute');
                sidebar.height($(".wrapper").height());
                if (_this.hasBindedResize) {
                    return;
                }
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    _this._fix(sidebar);
                });
                _this.hasBindedResize = true;
            } else {
                sidebar.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'height': 'auto'
                });
            }
        },
        _fixForFixed: function (sidebar) {
            sidebar.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'max-height': '100%',
                'overflow': 'auto',
                'padding-bottom': '50px'
            });
        },
        _fixForContent: function (sidebar) {
            $(".content-wrapper, .right-side").css('min-height', sidebar.height());
        }
    };

}
```

```css
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:pink
}

.control-sidebar-bg {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 0;
}
.control-sidebar-bg,
.control-sidebar {
  top: 0;
  right: -430px;
  width: 430px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.control-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 1010;
}

.control-sidebar > .tab-content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.control-sidebar.control-sidebar-open,
.control-sidebar.control-sidebar-open + .control-sidebar-bg {
  right: 0;
}
.control-sidebar-open .control-sidebar-bg,
.control-sidebar-open .control-sidebar {
  right: 0;
}

.control-sidebar-heading {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.control-sidebar-subheading {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu > li > a:before,
.control-sidebar-menu > li > a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.control-sidebar-menu > li > a:after {
  clear: both;
}
.control-sidebar-menu > li > a > .control-sidebar-subheading {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.control-sidebar-menu .menu-icon {
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu .menu-info {
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu .menu-info > .control-sidebar-subheading {
  margin: 0;
}
.control-sidebar-menu .menu-info > p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.control-sidebar-menu .progress {
  margin: 0;
}
.control-sidebar-dark {
  color: #b8c7ce;
}
.control-sidebar-dark,
.control-sidebar-dark + .control-sidebar-bg {
  background: #222d32;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs {
  border-bottom: #1c2529;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a {
  background: #181f23;
  color: #b8c7ce;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-left-color: #141a1d;
  border-bottom-color: #141a1d;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:focus,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:active {
  background: #1c2529;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:focus,
.control-sidebar-dark .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:active {
  background: #222d32;
  color: #fff;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .control-sidebar-heading,
.control-sidebar-dark .control-sidebar-subheading {
  color: #fff;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .control-sidebar-menu > li > a:hover {
  background: #1e282c;
}
.control-sidebar-dark .control-sidebar-menu > li > a .menu-info > p {
  color: #b8c7ce;
}
.control-sidebar-light {
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
.control-sidebar-light,
.control-sidebar-light + .control-sidebar-bg {
  background: #f9fafc;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs {
  border-bottom: #d2d6de;
}
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a {
  background: #e8ecf4;
  color: #444444;
}
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-left-color: #d2d6de;
  border-bottom-color: #d2d6de;
}
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:focus,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li > a:active {
  background: #eff1f7;
}
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:focus,
.control-sidebar-light .nav-tabs.control-sidebar-tabs > li.active > a:active {
  background: #f9fafc;
  color: #111;
}
.control-sidebar-light .control-sidebar-heading,
.control-sidebar-light .control-sidebar-subheading {
  color: #111;
}
.control-sidebar-light .control-sidebar-menu {
  margin-left: -14px;
}
.control-sidebar-light .control-sidebar-menu > li > a:hover {
  background: #f4f4f5;
}
.control-sidebar-light .control-sidebar-menu > li > a .menu-info > p {
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
  <!-- Content of the sidebar goes here -->
</aside>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="control-sidebar">This button opens the sidebar</button>

<button class="click">Add Stuff</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are appending the `button` here,

```
$(".box").append(stuff);
```

The events for the page has already been binded to the "existing" DOM elements. You are introducing a new "element" which fails to get the bind reference. 
You need to bind click event to `o.toggleBtnSelector` directly instead of doing `var btn = $(o.toggleBtnSelector);`

This is the working [JS Fiddle Link.](https://jsfiddle.net/3zxserkp/1/)